# How can I create a java program to find the amount of consecutive numbers in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to make a Java program to find the number of consecutive numbers in an array. For example, if an array has the values, 1,8,10,4,2,3 there are 4 numbers that are consecutive (1,2,3,4). I've created this program, but I'm getting an error on lines 28 and 31 for ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, how do I fix the error? (I'm not even sure if the program I made will work if the errors are fixed). Note: I know there are many solutions online for this but I'm a beginner programmer, and I'm trying to do this a more simple way.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    consec();
    

  }
    
    static void consec()
    {
            
      int[] nums = {16, 4, 5, 200, 6, 7, 70, 8};
      int counter=0;
      
      Arrays.sort(nums);
      for (int i=0; i < nums.length; i++)
        if (i != nums.length - 1)
          System.out.print(nums[i] + ", ");
        else
          System.out.print(nums[i]);

      for (int i=0; i < nums.length; i++)
        
        for (int j=i; j < nums.length - i; j++)
          if (nums[j + 1] - 1 == nums[j])
            counter++;
          
            else if (nums[j+1]==counter)
              System.out.print("Consective amount is" + counter);
            
   
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs (`https://ericlippert.com/`)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). --- A remark: If we write a post that has an exception at its core, we should always include the stack trace and highlight the line(s) throwing the exception.

Comment: When `j == nums.length - 1` (which happens when `i == 0`), then `nums[j + 1]` is out of bounds.

Comment: Ok, what do you expect for an array of numbers like `{ 4, 3, 10, 11, 6, 1, 4, 8, 7 }`  The sequences are `{10,11}, {3,4}, and {6,7,8}`.   The largest is of size `3` but the sum of them is `7`.  So what do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue for the exception lies within the access of `nums[j + 1]`.
Note that j can be as large as `nums.length - 1` due to the for loop.
Thus j + 1 can be nums.length which is an OutOfBounds array index.

Secondly I don't think your code solves the task - for example you only print a result if the number of consecutive numbers you've counted appears within the array. However I don't see how these things should correlate.
You can solve the problem like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
  if (nums[i-1] == nums[i] - 1) {
    counter+= 2;
    int j = i + 1;
    while (j < nums.length && nums[j] - 1 == nums[j-1]) {
      j++;
      counter++;
    }
    i = j;
  }
}
System.out.print("Consective amount is" + counter);
```

Note that the index i starts at 1, thus we can be assured that nums[i-1] exists.
If nums has only one element we should not run into any issues as the condition `i < nums.length` would not be fulfilled. We count two consequitves for every start of a sequence and one addition element for every following consequtive (while loop).
When the sequence ends we try finding a new sequence behind it by moving the index i to the end of the last sequence (j = i).

The above code will sum multiple distinct sequences of consequtive numbers. For example the array [17,2,20,18,4,3] has five consequitve numbers (2,3,4 and 17,18)

The algorithm has a time colpexity within O(n) as we either increase i or j by at least on and skip i to j after each sequence.

Comment: If you're summing up sequences > 1, then `{ 4, 3, 10, 11, 6, 1, 4, 8, 7 }` is `{3,4},{10,11},{6,7,8}`would be 7, not 5.

Comment: @WJS you are right. I was missing some brackets, the while loop should only start if the if condition is true and the start of a sequence was found. I fixed above code.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend re-thinking your approach to scanning over the array. Ideally you should only require one for-loop for this problem.

I personally created a HashSet of Numbers, which cannot hold duplicates. From there, you can iterate from `1` to `nums.length-1`, and check if `nums[i] - 1 == nums[i-1]` (ie: if they're consecutive). If they are equal, you can add both numbers to the HashSet.

Finally, you actually have the set of consecutive numbers, but for this question, you can simply return the size of the set.

I **strongly** recommend you attempt this problem and follow my explanation. If you simply require the code, this is the method that I came up with.

```
public static int countConsecutive(int[] nums) {
    Set<Integer> consecutive = new HashSet<>();

    if (nums.length <= 1)
        return 0;
    Arrays.sort(nums);

    for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] != nums[i - 1] + 1)
            continue;
        consecutive.add(nums[i]);
        consecutive.add(nums[i - 1]);
    }
    return consecutive.size();
}
```

Comment: I wasn't certain what the OP wanted so I ran your code. How do you get `5` for `{ 4, 3, 10, 11, 6, 1, 4, 8, 7 };`  The largest sequence is of length `3`.  But the sum of all sequences > 1 is 7.

Comment: @WJS There are 5 consecutive numbers in that array. 3, 4 and 6, 7, 8.

Comment: what about 10 and 11?  There are three groupings of consecutive numbers in there.  The two you mentioned and 10 and 11.

Comment: Good catch, modified the code to catch the largest numbers.

Comment: So the OP wants to sum the lengths of all the sequences of length > 1?  It wasn't clear to me from the OP's example.

Comment: Agreed. Clarity is needed from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach where sorting is not necessary.  It uses a `BitSet`.  And as in your example, is presumes positive numbers (`BitSet` doesn't permit setting negative positions).

```
int[] values = {4, 3, 10, 11, 6, 1, 4, 8, 7};
```

set the corresponding bit positions based on the values.

```
BitSet bits = new BitSet();
for (int i : values) {
    bits.set(i);
}
```

Initialize some values for output, starting bit position, and the set length.

```
BitSet out = new BitSet();
int start = 0;
int len = bits.length();
```

Now iterate over the bit set finding the range of bits which occupy adjacent positions.  Those will represent the consecutive sequences generated when populating the original BitSet. Only sequences of two or more are displayed.

```
while (start < len) {
    start = bits.nextSetBit(start);
    int end = bits.nextClearBit(start+1);
    if (start != end-1) {
        // populate the subset for output.
        out.set(start,end);
        System.out.println(out);
    }
    out.clear();
    start = end;
}
```

prints

```
{3, 4}
{6, 7, 8}
{10, 11}
```

If you just want the largest count, independent of the actual values, it's even simpler.  Just use this in place of the above after initializing the bit set.

```
int len = bits.length();
int total = 0;
while (start < len) {
    start = bits.nextSetBit(start);
    int end = bits.nextClearBit(start + 1);
    if (end - start > 1) {
        total += end - start;
    }
    start = end;
}
System.out.println(total);
```